# How to copy/paste values in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have inserted the formula `=today()` which gives me today's date.
I want it to be retained tomorrow as today's date.

In Excel I would use `Copy` / `Paste Values` to overwrite the formula with the result.
I do not seem to be able to do that with OpenOffice Calc.

I uncheck `formula` and check `date & time` but all that happens is that the formula disappears leaving me with a blank cell.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the *Openoffice* you can use the same approach:

1. Copy the cell with the formula `=today()` with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. Use **paste special** with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shitf</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
3. In the windows that will open check only

   - `Date & Time`
   - and **`Formats`**. (Else you'll see a number that is the internal representation of the date).

   It will copy the current date *fixed* as you want...

---

Note:

- When try to *copy & paste special* checking only `Text` and `Numbers` I obtain only and empty cell.
- Tested on *Openoffice* Version: 4.2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Select your cell or column and click *Data → Text to Columns.* to change a 'text' type number to a numeric number.

This in particular also works, if your formula yields a number formatted as text, e.g., if your cell A1 contains `Bob190` data, then `=Mid(A1;4;3)` yields `190`, however, as text, not as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Copy cell then use dropdown arrow next to paste icon in toolbar and paste as Unformatted text or RTF.
Some of the other options here may also work but limit what can be done with the pasted content.